# <input type="button"> doesn't inherit the font-family

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

**Hi everyone, I have a question, hope it helps**

**with code**

```css
.common{
    font-family: "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック";
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="common" >
            <input type="button" value=button> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**On Chrome buttons do not inherit font-family of `<td>`**

**On IE buttons inherit font-family of `<td>` , but do not inherit  color: #FFFFFF of `<td>`**

**Why is there this difference?**

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that your button doesn't inherit from the parent CSS because the button already has an assigned CSS (you can see it when you inspect your element online). This assigned CSS is different depending on the web browsers.
So you have to force the css as @Amri advised you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you have any source for "This assigned CSS is different depending on the web browsers." ?
I want to know on IE what properties should be inherited like "font-family", and not inherited like "color"

Comment: Sorry I don't, but you can inspect your element on different web bowser. In any case, the most relevant would be to cover all the cases and force everything you need.

Comment: Your welcome, if one of the answers seems to answer your problem, consider validating it with the green check to the left of the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can specified it with:

```
table tr td .common{
    font-family: "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック";
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,
But I want to learn how it works, why there are inheritance cases, there are non-inheritance cases,
Do you have any source material about this?

Comment: see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

hope it can help you.

Comment: @Anna not sure why you accepted this answer. First it doesn't work, second it doesn't explain anything

Comment: I pressed the wrong button while viewing the answer, sorry for the mistake